# How to mock the IElasticClient Get method?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, elasticsearch, moq, nest

Here's a minimal repro of my class that handles communication with Elasticsearch through Nest 1.7:

```
public class PeopleRepository
{
    private IElasticClient client;

    public PeopleRepository(IElasticClient client)
    {
        this.client = client;
    }

    public Person Get(string id)
    {
        var getResponse = client.Get<Person>(p => p.Id(id));

        // Want to test-drive this change:
        if (getResponse.Source == null) throw new Exception("Person was not found for id: " + id);

        return getResponse.Source;
    }
}
```

As noted in the code, I'm trying to test-drive a certain change. I'm using NUnit 2.6.4 and Moq 4.2 to try to do this, in the following manner:

```
[Test]
public void RetrieveProduct_WhenDocNotFoundInElastic_ThrowsException()
{
    var clientMock = new Mock<IElasticClient>();
    var getSelectorMock = It.IsAny<Func<GetDescriptor<Person>, GetDescriptor<Person>>>();
    var getRetvalMock = new Mock<IGetResponse<Person>>();

    getRetvalMock
        .Setup(r => r.Source)
        .Returns((Person)null);

    clientMock
        .Setup(c => c.Get<Person>(getSelectorMock))
        .Returns(getRetvalMock.Object);

    var repo = new PeopleRepository(clientMock.Object);

    Assert.Throws<Exception>(() => repo.Get("invalid-id"));
}
```

However, I've mocked the various ElasticClient bits incorrectly: the `Get` method on `IElasticClient` returns null, thus causing a NullReferenceException on `getResponse.Source` before my code gets to throw the exception I want it to throw.

How do I properly mock the `Get<T>` method on `IElasticClient`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use the `It.IsAny` method outside of the `Setup` call otherwise it treats it as null. Moving the `It.IsAny` into the setup should work:

```
 clientMock
        .Setup(c => c.Get<Person>(It.IsAny<Func<GetDescriptor<Person>, GetDescriptor<Person>>>()))
        .Returns(getRetvalMock.Object);
```

Comment: Wow, super fast response. Glad I asked, had not thought of this :O